# Editor Control - Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, rad

I'm quite new to asp.net,could someone please suggest me options to implement the below explained functionality in asp.net

1) I need to create a template (a system/user preference) as below

[image]

I guess I could use controls like TinyMCE/Rad editor for this, plz. advise

2) The template created as explained above should then be persisted and later be used to create actual (html) content and display it in a (Literal) control as below

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try : http://freetextbox.com/

FreeTextBox HTML Editor: [Demo](http://freetextbox.com/demos/everything.aspx)

and

http://www.tinymce.com/

TinyMCE - Javascript WYSIWYG Editor: [Demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

Comment: I decided to stick with RadEditor and asp.net - Literal controls, thanks.